# Limit of succession of the diameter of homeomorphic compact spaces

Tags: general-topology, limits, metric-spaces

Let $A_1$ be a compact metric space and let $a_1 \in A_1$

Let $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of subset of $A_1$ such that $A_{n+1} \subsetneq A_n$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \{a_1\}$

Let $B_1$ be a compact metric space and let $f:A_1 \to B_1$ be a homeomorphism and let $B_n=f(A_n)$

Does it exist any theorems that helps me to find 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} 
\dfrac
{diam(B_n)}
{diam(A_n)}
$$

I mean $diam(X)=\sup_{x,y \in X}d(x,y)$

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any $\lambda>0$.

Take $$A_n=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2| x^2+y^2\leq \frac1n\right\}\\
B_n=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2| x^2+y^2\leq \frac{\lambda}{n}\right\}$$

Then, define $f$ as $f((x,y))=(\lambda x, \lambda y)$.

Then, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{diam(B_n)}{diam(A_n)} = \lambda$$

So no, you cannot say anything about the limit because the limit can be any positive real number.

Comment: thanks for you answer